# Obtain a date range from a single date

Tags: ruby, date, date-range

I can do this myself of course, but is there built-in functionality in Ruby, or a library, that would let me do something like this

```
date = Time.now
sunday = date.week.first_day
saturday = date.week.last_day
```

Thanks

Comment: You've asked 8 questions and haven't accepted any answers yet. If an answer has helped you then please accept it by clicking the tick to the left of the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [ActiveSupport](http://as.rubyonrails.org/) gem.  It, however, considers Monday as the start of the week.

```
require 'active_support'
d = Date.today                     # => Mon, 25 Jan 2010
sun = d.beginning_of_week - 1.day  # => Sun, 24 Jan 2010
sat = d.end_of_week - 1.day        # => Sat, 30 Jan 2010
```

Needs more work if today is Sunday

```
def week_ends(date)
  sun = date.beginning_of_week - 1.day
  sat = date.end_of_week - 1.day
  if date.sunday?
    sun += 1.week
    sat += 1.week
  end
  [sun, sat]
end

p d = Date.today
p week_ends(d)

p d = Date.yesterday
p week_ends(d)
```

results in

```
Mon, 25 Jan 2010
[Sun, 24 Jan 2010, Sat, 30 Jan 2010]
Sun, 24 Jan 2010
[Sun, 24 Jan 2010, Sat, 30 Jan 2010]
```

Answer (score 0):

Days are represented by 0..6, Sunday being 0.

```
date = Time.now
puts date.wday
```

would output todays number code of the week.

What are you trying to accomplish?

by adding or subtracting the number of seconds in a day you get to a different date exactly 1 day from now.

```
date = Time.now
puts date + 86400 #will be tomorrow
```

Comment: The questions specifically asks for a gem to streamline the visual representation of this operation (and those like it). This does not really answer his question.

Comment: Do you ever find that the client really doesn't know what he wants (not specifically referring to you, blogofsongs)